# Get coordinates once with CLLocation manager in iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I am using this code to get coordinates:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and then I am using the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

_currentLocation = [locations lastObject];


//Doing some stuff

//I am using stopUpdatingLocation but this delegate is called a lot of times
[_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];



 }
```

I actually want to get once the coordinates because  I want to avoid executing the code in the didUpdateLocation more than once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the location manager fires its updates many times, progressively getting more accurate location results.

One way to stop this is simply to use a boolean

```
BOOL _hasUpdatedUserLocation = NO;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (!_hasUpdatedUserLocation) {
        _hasUpdatedUserLocation = YES;
        ... // other code
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could kill the delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
    ... // other code
}
```